# Checking against a threshold and calculating the time duration

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
       Timestamp                               Signal
2020-01-01T10:25:44.000 - 6.00                   20
2020-01-01T10:25:45.000 - 6.00                   15 
2020-01-01T10:25:46.000 - 6.00                    8
2020-01-01T10:25:47.000 - 6.00                   17 
2020-01-01T10:25:48.000 - 6.00                   19
2020-01-01T10:25:49.000 - 6.00                   19
```

The timestamp column is a string and not converted to datetime. I want to compare the signal values against a threshold, for example 12 and calculate the time duration the signal stays above 12. So for the given dataset, the duration values will be [2,3] in seconds returned as a list/array. How do I do that in Python? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If it is guaranteed that there will be a row for every second,* then you can try to count the rows instead of getting a difference in timestamps.

Either way you need to identify consecutive rows above your threshold.

```
df['above'] = df.Signal.gt(12)
df['stint'] = (df.above.diff().fillna(0) != 0).cumsum()
# above is a boolean, so diff() will get +1 when stepping above 12 and -1 when stepping below
# !=0 will mark each step up/down with True
# cumsum() will create a 'stint ID' of sorts, so we can groupby it
```

Now, we can parse timestamp with `df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(dfTimestamp)` and get the difference between each step OR in this case it seems easier to just

```
stints = df.groupby(['stint', 'above']).Signal.size()
stints = stints.loc[stints.above==True]
```

Comment: It is guaranteed there will be a row for every second. My signal data is stored in a pandas series, so as per you code, I am writing ```above = Signal.gt(12)```. However, in the second line ```df.above.diff()``` is giving me error since my df has no attribute above. If I write ```above.diff()``` it says type object does not support item assignment. How do I correct that?

Comment: Since Signal is a pandas series, writing ```df.Signal.gt(12)``` is producing error. If I write ```df['above'] = Signal.gt(12)```, it says TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: I see, you stated in your question that it was a dataframe. Try `df = Signal.to_frame()` as the first line

Comment: Thank you, one additional question. How do I separate out the counts that corresponds to True since I want to track duration above the threshold and disregard the values below the threshold.

Comment: that one is my bad... see edit to the last portion of code